# How do I save the scrollback buffer in urxvt?

Tags: urxvt

Is there a way to save the scrollback buffer to a file in urxvt?

Alternatively: Is there a way to copy the scrollback buffer to the X clipboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out:

1. man -s1 urxvt
   read about print-pipe
2. man -s7 urxvt
   read about `ESC ] Ps;Pt ST`, when `Ps=55`

Comment: Awesome! I'm completely happy with *print-pipe*, so I didn't check the escape sequence, which is looking a little confusing...

Comment: Can someone explain this to someone who doesn't have several hours to read `man` pages? Should it be configured by default? If not, how is it configured? If it is configured, what is the actual, human readable keyboard shortcut? These `man` pages are absolutely obtuse.

Comment: Supposedly you put the following line in .Xdefaults `URxvt.print-pipe: cat > $(TMPDIR=$HOME mktemp urxvt.XXXXXX)` and then when you press Ctrl-Print you'll get a file named urxvt.9HrnkE in your home directory with the contents of the scrollback. However, this isn't happening for me, and I can't figure out why not.